# ngOnDestroy while reloading page

Tags: angular, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I'm trying to understand and experiment with Angular lifecycle hooks.

Regarding `ngOnDestroy`, in the official documentation it says:

> A lifecycle hook that is called when a directive, pipe, or service is destroyed. Use for any custom cleanup that needs to occur when the instance is destroyed.

So, I'm able to trigger the `ngOnDestroy` event when I redirect page. Strangely I am unable to trigger `ngOnDestroy` when I reload the page. Is it not going to destroy my directives, services when I reload the page? Why is `ngOnDestroy` not triggered on page reload?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50761416/ngondestroy-not-firing-on-page-reload

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50761416/ngondestroy-not-firing-on-page-reload):

> `ngOnDestroy` only fires when the component is destroyed inside the angular workflow. However, refreshing the page is outside of the workflow

Answer (score 3):

*ngOnDestroy* only gets fired when the component or service is destroyed inside the angular workflow. So, reloading or refreshing the page is out of the scope and hence this method does not fire.