# How to close the external window after logout in Angular 12?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular12

I created an external `window` in the Angular application, everything works fine but I want to `close` the external `window` after application logout

written the code below, I'm moving from 1 page to another page then the external window closing properly. If I press the logout button then the external window does not `close` (`ngOnDestroy` is not called in the case of application logout)

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.externalWindow = window.open('', '', `width=${this.wWidth},height=${this.wHeight},left=${this.wLeft},top=${this.wTop}`)

    this.host = new DomPortalOutlet(
      this.externalWindow.document.body,
      this.componentFactoryResolver,
      this.applicationRef,
      this.injector
    )

    this.host.attach(this.portal)
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.externalWindow.close()
  }
```

Comment: Open window button code and logout button code are in different components

Comment: Shouldn't matter in which components they are. Maybe I understand the question wrong, you want to close the open window by pressing a button inside it?

Comment: this.externalWindow in the window component, logout implementation in the layout component.
How can we call this.externalWindow.clsone() in layout component?

Comment: Found the solution and Updated

Answer (score 0):

```
this.externalWindow.close()
```

is indeed the functionality you need to use. The problem is that you need to trigger it upon logout `click` as well. You can have something like

```
onClick="closeExternalWindow()"
```

of course, you need to implement `closeExternalWindow` which does the logout for `externalWindow` and then call this function both on destroy and logout click.

Answer (score 0):

ngOnDestroy fires only when component destroys. In the logout use case, we are redirecting to the login URL which means it refreshes the page (This is outside angular workflow) hence ngOnDestroy not firing.

If I move 1 route to a different route within the application then ngOnDestroy fires and closes the external window.

This article helped me to find the solution
[ngOnDestroy not firing on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50761416/ngondestroy-not-firing-on-page-reload)

Solution:

```
ngOnInit() {
  window.onbeforeunload = () => this.ngOnDestroy()
}
```