# Angular Does ngOnDestroy run inside the service?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service this service should run until the project is started and closed. After the application(website) is closed, the ngondestroy method of the service should run. How do I know if the ngondestroy method in the service is working? does this ngondestroy work?

```
export class UserServiceService implements OnDestroy{
subsc : Subscription
constructor(private auth : AngularFireAuth,private db : AngularFireDatabase,private fnc:AngularFireFunctions,private router : Router,private tostr : ToastrService) {

 this.subsc =    this.auth.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      if (user) {
         this.db.database.ref("users/"+user.uid+"/shopCart/").on("value",snap=>{
         })
      } else {
        //not user
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("Closed")
    this.subsc.unsubscribe()
    this.db.database.ref("users/"+this.currentUserId+"/shopCart/").off()
  }
}
```

Comment: Browser garbage collects resources on page close. Given you've added logic to check user is defined (and so bad logic isn't running as page closes) and added ngOnDestroy for when service *could* be destroyed if provided to a smaller scope in application...I think this is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @nate-kumar said angular does not fire the `ngOnDestroy` life cycle hook when the user closes the browser.

**The best workaround for achieve this is to use something below :**

```
export class AppComponent {
  @HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ])
  unloadHandler(event) {
    // do the needful here
  }

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', [ '$event' ])
  beforeUnloadHandler(event) {
    // do the need full here
  }
}
```

**Please find the working stakblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgjybt?file=src/app/app.component.ts).**

Comment: you can fire an `alert('hello, world')` and check also you can record the devtool in chrome

Comment: if alert wont work u can write smth in localStorage

Comment: I put the alert and localstorage commands in the functions you wrote, but they didn't work. '  localStorage.setItem("Test","work?")
    alert('hello, world')'

Comment: Answer updated with the working example stackblitz please refer there

Answer (score 2):

`ngOnDestroy` unfortunately does not fire when a browser window is closed. It is only triggered when a component/service/directive is destroyed while the Angular application is alive.

If you need to trigger logic when the browser window is closed, some solutions have involved using the `onbeforeunload` hook on the `window` object:

See [ngOnDestroy not firing on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50761416/ngondestroy-not-firing-on-page-reload)

Comment: is ngOnDestroy triggered on browser reload or browser refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Angular service does not using `ngOnDestroy` by default but...

When implementing `ngOnDestroy` in service you can link it to a component `ngOnDestroy`.

Meaning when the component will get destroy the `ngOnDestroy` the `ngOnDestroy` of the service will get call also.

This is very useful if you want to unsubscribe or remove data when there is not need for it any more.

In order to link service `ngOnDestroy` to component `ngOnDestroy` add it to the component providers and implement `ngOnDestroy` in the service.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './app-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-test.component.scss'],
  providers: [YourService],

})
```

But for the case you mentioned check this [ngOnDestroy not firing on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50761416/ngondestroy-not-firing-on-page-reload)